# IOS/Objective-C: Call Hit Test Method On View

Tags: ios, objective-c, hittest

I cannot find in the documentation how you call the hit test method?  Is it called automatically as a delegate method?  Or how would you call it?  When I put the following code in a VC, it does not fire when you load or tap on the view.  Thanks for any suggestions.

```
  - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
NSLog(@"hit test firing");
       return self.view;
    }
```

Comment: It is a `UIView` method, not a `UIViewController` method. You can call it whenever you like.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance.  What is the code to call it?

Comment: You would call it via `[someUIViewObject hitTest:pointYouWantToTest, withEvent: nil]`, but as per my comment on the answer, explain what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: This previous question explains goal in more detail. I thought first step would be just to get method to fire.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251450/ios-objective-c-pass-touch-event-on-scrollview-to-view-below-using-hittouch

Comment: It called automatically.To understand the working of Hit test go through this document: http://smnh.me/hit-testing-in-ios/

Comment: Ok, if it is called automatically, where would I place above method so that it fires?  - (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
NSLog(@"hit test firing");
       return self.view;
    } I tried placing it in viewdidload of  VC, view willappear and so forth and it did not fire.  I want to add some additional code but first step is to get it to fire at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a method on `UIView`, here is the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622469-hittest

It will be called automatically by the system to determine which view has been tapped. You can override it if you want custom functionality.

Comment: So if I put that method in a viewcontroller, it should get called automatically?   Right now, it is not firing.

Comment: It will never be called for a UIViewController. It is a method on UIView, so it will only be called for UIView and its subclasses.

Comment: Where in the app should I place the code so that the NSLog statement will print out?  I want to verify that it is getting called.

Comment: You would need to add it to a `UIView` subclass.  If you haven't created any `UIView` subclasses that are in your view then there is nowhere you can add it.  I think, perhaps, you have an X-Y problem here.  What are you actually trying to achieve?  If you want to record taps on your view controller's base view then you will need to add a tap gesture recogniser to it.

Comment: I have a scrollview that is overlapping the bottom of a textview and absorbing touch events. There is a gesturerecognizer on both the scrollview for scrolling and the textview for touch events.  Have already used canceltouchesinView = NO.  I think I need to add hittest code so that the taps pass through to the textview.  But have not been able to figure out where to put hittest code.  I guess I have to create a category for scrollview?